# AspectFill works for CachedImage renderer in Xamarin Mac when an image is initially loaded, but not when value is updated

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

Xamarin Forms Mac has issues with their Images when it comes to aspectfill. I decided to do a workaround that works well when loaded initially (fills to the set position), but not if the image is changed.

I use FFImageLoading to add some more functionality to the Image.

This is the custom renderer:

```
    string src = null;
    NSImage img = null;
    CachedImage element = null;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CachedImage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        element = (CachedImage)this.Element;

        if (Control != null && element != null &&
            element.Aspect.ToString() == "AspectFill" &&
            element.Source != null)
        {
            Control.Layer = new CoreAnimation.CALayer();
            Control.Layer.ContentsGravity = CALayer.GravityResizeAspectFill;
            src = element.Source.ToString();

            if (src.StartsWith("File:"))
            {
                src = src.Replace("File:", "").Trim();
                if (src == "")
                    return;

                img = NSImage.ImageNamed(src);
            }
            else
            {
                src = src.Replace("Uri:", "").Trim();
                if (src == "")
                    return;

                img = FromUrl(src);
            }

            if (img != null)
            {
                Control.Layer.Contents = img.CGImage;
                Control.WantsLayer = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private NSImage FromUrl(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
            using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
                return new NSImage(data);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override NSBitmapImageRep BitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect(CGRect rect)
    {
        return base.BitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect(rect);
    }

    public override CALayer Layer
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Layer;
        }
        set
        {

            base.Layer = value;
        }
    }
```